# It is giving CORS error in server when deployed with Plesk for React JS and PHP Laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors

I am an app whose frontend is in React JS and backend is in Laravel. Both of them are deployed using Plesk. I have setup all necessary configurations in Laravel backend to handle CORS issues. But it is still giving CORS error.

Here is the content of the cors.php file in config folder in laravel backend.

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['url_of_react_app'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

It is still throwing CORS error. Both Laravel backend and react app is depolyed over https. The CORS error is like this.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL_of_laravel_backend' from origin
> 'URL_of_React_app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

The api configuration in React app is like this

```
import axios from "axios";

export const baseURL = "URL_of _laravel_backend";
export const axiosPublicInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
});
```

Comment: There are lots of CORS errors. Please paste the exact error message into your question. We don't get extra points for guessing! And also please show us the relevant frontend  code which is sending the request. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the post. Please check once again.

Comment: Thanks. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` is a **response** header and therefore does not belong in your axios request. It's up to the server to decide which origins are allowed, not the client - otherwise CORS would be completely pointless! Read [this excellent guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if you're not sure how CORS works. Anyway, remove that at least from your axios code, and try again. Even if it doesn't fix the issue alone, it certainly isn't helping.

Comment: Anyway regarding the main error, I can only assume maybe the CORS code in Laravel is not being triggered, or at least not for the specific request you're testing (which, I note, we still cannot see, we only have your basic axios initialisation code). You could try to debug to see why that is. It seems to be making a preflight OPTIONS request, so perhaps that is not handled by that bit of code or even not by Laravel at all. Laravel's not my area of expertise but some of [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+cors+preflight) might help you, I doubt you're the first person with this error

Comment: @ADyson I also have this doubt that it is making a preflight request. But as I searched it seems that the package in Laravel which handles the CORS issue automatically handles the preflight request also. If this is true, the error must not be because of not handling the preflight request properly . Well have to check if the Laravel backend indeed handling the preflight request in a proper way. I have also removed "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" this from request headers in React app, but still the same.

Comment: `I also have this doubt that it is making a preflight request`...you don't need to doubt it. It _is_ making a preflight request. The error message says it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the urls to the "paths" key, for example

```
<?php 
return [


   'paths' => [
                'api/*', 
                "example1/api/*", 
                "example1/example2/*", 
                "example3/example4/*"
           ],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => false,
    'max_age' => false,
    'supports_credentials' => false,  

];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check your version

php version : 8.1.23
Laravel version : 10.28.0**

It seems like you have the necessary configuration and setup for handling CORS in your Laravel project.
To further clarify the steps and provide proper documentation, here's a summary of what you've done to
resolve CORS issues when deploying your Laravel project with Plesk:

1.Make sure you have the correct Laravel version and PHP version in your environment.

2.In your **composer.json**, add the **"fruitcake/php-cors"** package with the desired version requirement:

```
 "require": {
    "fruitcake/php-cors": "^1.2"
}
```

3.Run **composer install** to install the required packages.

4.Use the **php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"** command to publish the CORS configuration file.
This step is important because it allows you to customize CORS settings.

5.In your **Kernel.php** file (usually located in app/Http/Kernel.php), add the following lines to enable CORS middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    // ...
];

protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'cors' => \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

With these configurations in place, your Laravel application should be ready to handle CORS requests.
This allows your React JS frontend to communicate with your PHP Laravel backend without CORS-related issues when deployed with Plesk.

By following these steps, you've properly set up CORS handling in your Laravel application.
It should help you avoid CORS errors when making requests from your React JS frontend to your Laravel API.